# check module destructor in Omnet++ with Veins

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I have a VANETs project, I work with veins-2.0-rc2.

In class LinearMobility.cc I have this code,

```
void LinearMobility::initialize(int stage)
{
  BaseMobility::initialize(stage);

  debugEV << "initializing LinearMobility stage " << stage << endl;

  if (stage == 0)
  {

    move.setSpeed(par("speed").doubleValue());
    acceleration = par("acceleration");
    angle = par("angle");
    angle = fmod(angle,360);
 }
 else if(stage == 1)
 {
    stepTarget = move.getStartPos();

    if(!world->use2D()) 
    {
        opp_warning("This mobility module does not yet support 3 dimensional movement."\
                    "Movements will probably be incorrect.");
    }
    if(!world->useTorus()) 
    {
        opp_warning("You are not using a torus (parameter \"useTorus\" in"\
                    "BaseWorldUtility module) playground but this mobility"\
                    "module uses WRAP as border policy.");
    }
  }
}
```

I try to add the accident event to my scenario by modifying the class LinearMobility.cc

```
void LinearMobility::initialize(int stage)
{

  BaseMobility::initialize(stage);

  debugEV << "initializing LinearMobility stage " << stage << endl;

if (stage == 0){

    move.setSpeed(par("speed").doubleValue());
    acceleration = par("acceleration");
    angle = par("angle");
    angle = fmod(angle,360);

    accidentCount = par("accidentCount");

    WATCH(angle);

    startAccidentMsg = 0;
    stopAccidentMsg = 0;

    if (accidentCount > 0) {
                simtime_t accidentStart = par("accidentStart");
                startAccidentMsg = new cMessage("scheduledAccident");
                stopAccidentMsg = new cMessage("scheduledAccidentResolved");
                scheduleAt(simTime() + accidentStart, startAccidentMsg);
            }
}
else if(stage == 1){
    stepTarget = move.getStartPos();

    if(!world->use2D()) {
        opp_warning("This mobility module does not yet support 3 dimensional movement."\
                    "Movements will probably be incorrect.");
    }
    if(!world->useTorus()) {
        opp_warning("You are not using a torus (parameter \"useTorus\" in"\
                    "BaseWorldUtility module) playground but this mobility"\
                    "module uses WRAP as border policy.");
    }
  }
 }

void LinearMobility::handleSelfMsg(cMessage *msg)
{
   if (msg == startAccidentMsg) {
    
    simtime_t accidentDuration = par("accidentDuration");
    scheduleAt(simTime() + accidentDuration, stopAccidentMsg);
    accidentCount--;
  }
  else if (msg == stopAccidentMsg) {
    
    if (accidentCount > 0) {
        simtime_t accidentInterval = par("accidentInterval");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + accidentInterval, startAccidentMsg);
    }
 }
}
```

But I have this problem in OMNeT++ :

> undisposed object: (cMessage) Scenario.node[0].mobility.scheduledAccidentResolved -- check module destructor
>
> undisposed object: (cMessage) Scenario.node[0].mobility.scheduledAccident -- check module destructor
>
> undisposed object: (cMessage) Scenario.node[1].mobility.move -- check module destructor
> undisposed object: (cMessage) Scenario.node[2].mobility.move -- check module destructor
> undisposed object: (cMessage) Scenario.node[3].mobility.move -- check module destructor
> undisposed object: (cMessage) Scenario.node[4].mobility.move -- check module destructor

Can anyone help me solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These messages inform you that you have created an object but you do not remove it. It concerns messages: `startAccidentMsg`, `stopAccidentMsg` and probably messages connected with moving.
Solution: inside `finish()` method add the following code:

```
cancelAndDelete(startAccidentMsg);
cancelAndDelete(stopAccidentMsg);
```

If there is no `finish()` method, just add it.

Comment: Yes I have the finish() method in my code: '                                               void LinearMobility::finish()
{
    statistics.stopTime = simTime();

    statistics.recordScalars(*this);

    cancelAndDelete(startAccidentMsg);
    cancelAndDelete(stopAccidentMsg);

    //isPreInitialized = false;
}'     But the same problem occur

Comment: I think that there is another error in your model. Try to set `debug-on-errors=true` in your `omnetpp.ini` and run your simulation in debug mode.

Comment: Please note what the OmNET++ manual states about the finish method: 'Record statistics. Do **not** delete anything or cancel timers -- all cleanup must be done in the destructor.' (https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:initialize-and-finish).
Also, the code should be guarded against nullpointers and the pointer should be reset after deleting the associated object to avoid duplicate frees.