# Undisposed object: message on omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am working with simulations in omnet++ and I am facing this error. Could anyone help me with this error in omnet++? I do not use any message of my own I am using TCP protocole in INET4 framework.

```
undisposed object: (omnetpp::cMessage) tcpwindowscale.client.tcp.conn-temp.IF-2ACK -- 
check module destructor
```

Comment: Please check SO for similar questions. One such answer that may be helpful is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543640/check-module-destructor-in-omnet-with-veins

Comment: Hi. Did you try the answer

Comment: Yes I did, but my problem was different. Thank you!